# How to create a single DataFrame column from two separate arrays being pulled through a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a DataFrame that prints precipitation type for multiple cities based on certain criteria. I have multiple variables that I would like to run through a single loop. For example, if temperature > 32 and precipitation amount > 0 then return "Rain". I use an API to pull current forecast data, so my actual TMP and precip arrays are different daily.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html on this page is what I am essentially trying to reproduce, except with more than just one condition so I can include more precipitation types.

```
TMP = [17, 16, 16, 15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 21, 23, 23]
precip = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017,0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.020, 0.025, 0.035, 0.017, 0.017,0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.02]

weather_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [TMP], 'B': [precip]})
  
def rain_condition(n):
  for n in range(TMP.size):
    if TMP[n] > 32 and precip[n] < 0.001:
      return "Dry"
    elif TMP[n] < 32 and precip[n] > 0.25: 
      return "Icing"
    return "Rain" 



def make_pretty(styler):
    styler.set_caption("Weather Conditions")
    styler.format(rain_condition)
    styler.background_gradient(axis=None,cmap="YlGnBu", vmin=0.001,vmax=5)
    return styler

s = weather_df2.style.pipe(make_pretty)
s
```

This creates two columns taking TMP and precip separately, I want weather_df2 to have one column. It works if I just use TMP, but I need an if and condition.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you [please share the data as text and not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)? Given the data seems to be available within the module you are using, may be you could update the question with code to generate the data? Ideally, the best way to ask a question could be to post [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
import pandas as pd


def rain_condition(tmp, _precip):
    """
    Calculate the rain condition based on the temperature and precipitation.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    tmp : list
        Temperatures.
    _precip : list
        Precipitation values.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        A DataFrame with rain conditions.
    """
    result = []
    for n in range(min([len(tmp), len(_precip)])):
        if tmp[n] > 32 and _precip[n] < 0.001:
            result.append("Dry")
        elif tmp[n] < 32 and _precip[n] > 0.25: 
            result.append("Icing")
        result.append("Rain")
    return pd.DataFrame({'Weather': result})


def background_highlight(v):
    """
    Highlight the background in a different color depending on the value.

    Parameters
    ----------
    v : Any
        The value to be highlighted.

    Returns
    -------
    str | None
        The CSS property to apply.
    """
    if v == 'Rain':
        return 'color:white;background-color:#53789E'
    return 'background-color:#DBF1FD' if v == 'Icing' else None


def make_pretty(styler, hide_columns: bool = True):
    """Format a DataFrame with a Styler.

    Parameters
    ----------
    styler : pd.Styler | pd.DataFrame | pd.Series
        The Styler, or DataFrame to format.
    hide_columns : bool, default True
        Whether to hide the column names.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.Styler
        The formatted Styler.
    """
    if isinstance(styler, pd.Series):
        styler = styler.to_frame()
    if isinstance(styler, pd.DataFrame):
        return make_pretty(styler.style)
    if hide_columns:
        styler.hide_columns()
    styler.set_caption("<h2>Weather Conditions</h2>")
    styler.background_gradient(axis=None, cmap="YlGnBu", vmin=0.001, vmax=5)
    return styler.applymap(background_highlight)


TMP = [17, 16, 16, 33, 14, 14, 13, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 21, 23, 23]
precip = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017, 0.017,0.017, 0.017,
          0.017, 0.017, 0.020, 0.26, 0.035, 0.32, 0.017,0.017, 0.017]

s = rain_condition(TMP, precip).pipe(make_pretty)
s
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Notes

- Instead of creating the dataframe `weather_df2`, prior to calling the `rain_condition` function, I've modified it to instead generate the dataframe that will then be styled later on.
- I've modified the function `make_pretty` so that it converts `pandas.Series` or `pandas.DataFrame` objects to `pandas.Styler`, in order to make it more robust.